# Javascript accessing parent function variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi I have a Question about accessing variables that are in a parent function

```
var DateRangePicker = function (name, clickFunction) {
    this.context = name;
    this.UpdateGraph = clickFunction;
    this.FinalDate = function () {
        var Dates = $(this.context).find("[name=datepickerText]").val().split('-');
        return Dates[1];
    };
    this.InitialDate = function () {
        var Dates = $(this.context).find("[name=datepickerText]").val().split('-   ');
       return Dates[0];
    };
    $(this.context).find("[name=UpdateDatepicker]").click(function () {
        var pickerText = $(InnerContext).find('[name=datepickerText]');
        var dates = pickerText.val().split('-');
        UpdateGraph(InitialDate(), FinalDate());
        $(context).find("[name=Toogler]").click();
    });
    return this;
}
```

How can i access the "this.UpdateGraph()" function inside the updateDatepicker click so far it sais that UpdateGraph and this.UpdateGraph doesnt exists

Comment: define var `self = this` in parent function and use `self.UpdateGraph` in child function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `this` context to your handler function, to keep from having an extra scope variable:

```
$(this.context).find("[name=UpdateDatepicker]").click(function () {
    var pickerText = $(this.InnerContext).find('[name=datepickerText]');
    var dates = pickerText.val().split('-');
    this.UpdateGraph(this.InitialDate(), this.FinalDate());
    $(this.context).find("[name=Toogler]").click();
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  Make sure to mark an answer as accepted when you find the one that best addresses your question, so people searching know which answer worked.